# List of IBM devices

Tags: ibm-quantum-devices

A few weeks ago I was on a website that had a list of IBM quantum devices and it showed the topology and frequency of each of the qubits but I can't seem to find that anymore. I was hoping that someone here could point me in that direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find an official and public list of all currently used IBM devices on their website: https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/services/resources?limit=50.

Comment: Thank you! I spent nearly half an hour looking for this! I can't accept answers until after 10 minutes so I'll accept this later.